# How to fix problem in multiplying table code scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket, multiplication

I have a code that puts the multiplying table, one should put `(multiplying-table 10 3)` and should get a list like `'(3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30)`, but instead my code gives me `'((((((((((() 3) 6) 9) 12) 15) 18) 21) 24) 27) 30)`, and I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```lisp
(define (multiplying-table n value)
  (cond ((= n 0) '())
        (else (list (multiplying-table (- n 1) value) (* n value)))))
```

Comment: You already posted this question, no need to duplicate it Carlos.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez -- this is a new question; OP has made a change to the code, which does not work as expected. OP's new question is about how to fix the updated code.

Comment: @adabsurdum I still think it's the same question, in essence. OP can edit the original, it's still not accepted.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez ok then, il go edit the original

Comment: The solution on the other question uses an accumulator; if this is not acceptable, maybe OP can describe why that won't work for them.